# How to divide in java using double and not get decimals

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to convert from seconds into years and days using a scanner object. I have got the answer but I have decimals that I need to get rid of. I thought getting rid of all the zeros would do it but it didn't work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework2_7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //tell user to input data
        System.out.print("enter a value for minutes:");
        double minutes = input.nextDouble();

        //equation
        System.out.print( minutes / 5256e2 + " years and " + ( minutes % 5256e2 ) / 144e1 + " days.");
    }

}
```

> enter a value for minutes:1e9
>
> 1902.5875190258753 years and 214.44444444444446 days.

Comment: Why is a "value for minutes" a `double`, after all? Shouldn't it be a plain `int`?

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: I use double because that is what the teacher wants us to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the final number into a integer, that will remove the decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Math.round() for this.

```
System.out.print(Math.round(minutes / 5256e2) + " years and " + Math.round( minutes % 5256e2  / 144e1) + " days.");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want rounding, you can use `String.format` to omit the decimals when printing.

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.0f years and %.0f days.",
                                 minutes / 5256e2,
                                 (minutes % 5256e2) / 144e1));
```